# XeLaTeX and ifplatform/catchfile (loaded by "minted"): Errors on compilation

Tags: errors, xetex, minted, catchfile, ifplatform

**FOR THE RECORD**

I was unable to test any of the solutions provided, as I changed my main system last year. After that, no more problems arose. I suspect the old system had problems with the hard drive. Either that or the operating system was failing.

I'm using `minted` along with `XeLaTeX`, but recently I've run into strange problems. To illustrate what I mean, consider the following MWE (the filename is `main.tex`):

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minted}[autogobble]{c}
        #include <stdio.h>
        int main() {
            printf("Hello World!\n");
            return 0;
        }
    \end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Compiling it with `pdflatex --shell-escape` generates the document correctly. Not so with `xelatex --shell-escape`, which outputs the following error:

```
! Package catchfile Error: File `main.w18' not found.

See the catchfile package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.93     \CatchFileDef\@tempa{\ip@file}{}
```

Am I missing something specific to `XeLaTeX` that makes `minted` work as expected?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I have discovered that logging out or rebooting the computer *temporarily* solves the problem. I attach general information about the system I'm currently using and the log here for more details:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=xelatex 2015.8.10)  22 SEP 2015 19:01
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**proba.tex
(./proba.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/minimal.cls
Document Class: minimal 2001/05/25 Standard LaTeX minimal class
) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/minted/minted.sty
Package: minted 2015/09/09 v2.1 Yet another Pygments shim for LaTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty
Package: fancyvrb 2008/02/07

Style option: `fancyvrb' v2.7a, with DG/SPQR fixes, and firstline=lastline fix 
<2008/02/07> (tvz)
\FV@CodeLineNo=\count79
\FV@InFile=\read1
\FV@TabBox=\box26
\c@FancyVerbLine=\count80
\FV@StepNumber=\count81
\FV@OutFile=\write3
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty
Package: float 2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
\c@float@type=\count82
\float@exts=\toks15
\float@box=\box27
\@float@everytoks=\toks16
\@floatcapt=\box28
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
Package: calc 2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count83
\calc@Bcount=\count84
\calc@Adimen=\dimen102
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen103
\calc@Askip=\skip41
\calc@Bskip=\skip42
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count85
\calc@Cskip=\skip43
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifplatform/ifplatform.sty
Package: ifplatform 2010/10/22 v0.4 Testing for the operating system

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is not detected.
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: pdfTeX >= 1.30 not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode not found.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/catchfile.sty
Package: catchfile 2011/03/01 v1.6 Catch the contents of a file (HO)
)
runsystem(uname -s > "proba.w18")...executed.



! Package catchfile Error: File `proba.w18' not found.

See the catchfile package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.93     \CatchFileDef\@tempa{\ip@file}{}

? x

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1071 strings out of 493708
 17078 string characters out of 6145891
 71205 words of memory out of 5000000
 4449 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1328 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 37i,0n,19p,243b,18s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
```

- Xubuntu 15.04
- TeXLive 2015
- `minted` 2.1

**EDIT 2:** I could trick `xelatex` into thinking `main.w18` had been created by executing `uname -s > main.w18` beforehand. However, this new error appears:

```
! Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this package.
```

Of course, I have `pygmentize` installed, as I can compile sometimes.

**EDIT 3:** After fiddling around, it seems `XeLaTeX` is unable to write files to the filesystem. I tried reinstalling TeXLive with no luck.

Comment: Adding information about your operating system, TeX installation, and version of `minted`, plus the complete log, might help. This is coming from `ifplatform` line 93 (83 in the docs, due to comments), which is using `catchfile`. Neither of those packages has been changed in years according to CTAN, and the recent releases of `minted` haven't changed anything that should affect those packages (`minted` just loads `ifplatform` to get `\ifwindows`). So this is strange.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm using Xubuntu 15.04, with TeXLive 2015 and `minted` 2.1. And about the log, as I started fiddling around, I deleted it and started from scratch again! I have some more information, though: only after rebooting my computer, this MWE started working as expected! Pretty strange, indeed. By the way, I'm having this annoying error once in a while, with no apparent reason.

Comment: I tried the example document with an Lubuntu 14.04 virtual machine with a completely updated TeX Live 2015, and couldn't get any errors. Tracking this down will probably be tricky.

Comment: @G.Poore I know, pretty strange. Will this problem show up again, I'll update this with more information. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @G.Poore, I've added more information at your request. Hope it'll be useful :)

Comment: It looks like `uname` is failing sometimes. I have no idea what would cause that. I've added `ifplatform` and `catchfile` to your question title. Maybe someone with more Linux knowledge will see that and have some ideas.

Comment: @G.Poore Being curious with what `uname -s` meant, it just simply outputs "Linux", so it seems that `main.w18` contains only "Linux" in my specific case. In fact, it turns out that `uname -s` prints the kernel name. I bet the problem relies on *writing* that into the file.

Comment: I tried a Xubuntu virtual machine and got no problem (but TeX Live is still 2014). The file `<filename>.w18` is read in with no issue.

Comment: @egreg It's really strange, the OS is not virtualized in my machine. It happens from time to time, with no apparent pattern or cause. Anyway, I appreciate you've tested it.

Comment: I have edited the question, including behaviour after artificially creating `main.w18` beforehand.

Comment: It seems `XeLaTeX` is unable to write to the filesystem. Any file it tries to write cannot be saved, but no errors are raised.

Comment: Can you try running `xetex` on a file containing `\newwrite\temp\immediate\openout\temp=xyz.xyz \immediate\write\temp{Hello}\bye` and tell if the file is written out?

Comment: @egreg For now it is, as expected. I'll tell you whenever it can't.

Comment: Might it be related to now having enough memory (RAM)? I am running into this issue on a restricted 1G memory AWS machine with no swap

Answer (score 4):

Add `\usepackage{shellesc}` in main.tex before `\usepackage{minted}`

Comment: A little more explanation would be nice.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'll check trying that and get back to you as soon as possible. A little more explanation, as @HeikoOberdiek said, would be nice, though.

Comment: Worked for me; I think it works because `lualatex --shell-escape` doesn't work anymore.